# How to serve a picture in webp format with a space in the name?

Tags: nginx, server, webp

I tried to find information on how to do what I need - but to my surprise there was nothing at all, so I'm writing here.

### TASK

Convert all images to .webp format and replace original images by them.

### WHAT I DID

Converted all the images to .webp and put them near to the original images:

```
- assets/img/img.png
- assets/img/img.webp
- ...
```

Added rules for nginx.

```
# in http section
map $http_accept $webp_ext {
    default "";
    "~*webp" ".webp";
}

# in server section
location ~* ^(/.+)\.(png|jpe?g)$ {
    set $img_path $1;
    add_header Vary Accept;
    try_files $img_path$webp_ext $uri =404;
}
```

Its works for images that are named **without space** in name like `img.png`

But dont work for images like `img space.png`

[How it looks in the Network panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EzEQ.png)

---

**How i can serve it?**

P.S. I tried do this on `Apache` and **its work** for both images with this `.htaccess` rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Check if browser supports WebP images
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp

  # Check if WebP replacement image exists
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f

  # Serve WebP image instead
  RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Vary: Accept for all the requests to jpeg, png and gif
  Header append Vary Accept env=REQUEST_image
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType image/webp .webp
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

$uri has %20 decoded while $img_path is not.
rewrite should help here:

```
location ~ ^(?<basename>.*)\.(?<extension>png|jpe?g)$ {
rewrite .* $basename break;
try_files $uri.webp $uri.$extension =404;
}
```

with the changes to account for 'http_accept' of course

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my strength is not enough to understand what exactly i need to write in the http section. I understand that i need write `map`, but how exactly?
Can u show full work example pls?

Comment: The map from the ticket will do (for webp_ext). I would change it a little bit (removing '.' and adding default extension) :
`map $http_accept $webp_ext {
    default $extension;
    "~*webp" "webp";
}

....

location ~ ^(?<basename>.*)\.(?<extension>png|jpe?g)$ {
rewrite .* $basename break;
try_files $uri.$webp_ext $uri.$extension =404;
}`